# how to reach element of json array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using new Date function for countdown timer and ı want to load dates from json

my code like this.

home.ts

```
export class HomePage     {
 public products: any;
 private eventDate: Date = new Date('July 20, 2019 03:24:00');

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController ,    public navParams: NavParams,
    public myService : MyServiceProvider,public http: Http,) {

      this.loadProducts();

}

this.eventDate=new Date(this.products[0].start_time);

loadProducts(){
  this.myService.load()
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.products= data;

});
}
```

and I am experiencing this error

Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: HI, can you put `this.eventDate=new Date(this.products[0].start_time);` under `this.loadProducts();` in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this value `this.eventDate=new Date(this.products[0].start_time);` inside `.then` of `loadProducts()` method.

Comment: Why, what's the use of it?

Comment: this.loadProducts(); this function is calling api.. this will go in event loop. then browser will start executing `this.eventDate=new Date(this.products[0].start_time)`, where `this.products` is undefined yet.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work to your application. Check has there any data to products array.

```
export class HomePage {
  public products: any;
  private eventDate: Date = new Date('July 20, 2019 03:24:00');

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController
    , public navParams: NavParams
    , public myService: MyServiceProvider
    , public http: Http) {
    this.loadProducts();
  }  

loadProducts(){
  this.myService.load()
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.products = data;

      if(this.products.length > 0) {
        this.eventDate = new Date(this.products[0].start_time);
      }
    });
}
```